# How to display Static Boxes in a row (rather than on top of each other)

Tags: static-block

I am trying to add multiple static boxes in the same category. I am able to add them via short code by calling several at a time, but the boxes (which utilize images and links) only appear/show up on top of each other. I need them to list in a row (ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, next line down: 5, 6, 7, 8). Is there a way to get them to list in a row in short code?

Comment: you need to work with css. share the link of the page where the static blocks are shown

Comment: OK. Here is the link: http://randallsperformance.com/power-stroke/2011-2015-6-7l.html

Comment: first of all remove the `<p></p>` tags from the content of static blocks, use one parent `div` tag for each set and then keep the Name and image within the `div`. like `<div><span>name</span><a><img src="...."/></a><div>` and same for each next set ...

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple ways to implement it. But in every method, you need to  play with css ofcourse. Following code is a hint. You can use it. This would be the reliable method that you can hang on

In this code, I assume you want to show those static block section on all category pages. So our first step will be layout definition

file : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/test/test.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="my_custom_block" template="test/test.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_cateogory_view>
```

This will add a block in every category page. Currently it will show at bottom part of the page. However you can adjust its postion using `before` and `after` attributes.

Now we need to define the template file

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/test/test.phtml`

Here you need to define your html design. This template file will hold our static blocks

```
<!-- this is the container of static blocks-->
<div class="static-block-contianer">

    <!-- this is the left block-->
    <div class="left-section">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block1')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- this is the middle block-->
    <div class="middle-section">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block2')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- this is the right block-->
    <div class="right-section">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block3')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

In the example shown above, I have shown a demo code, that will allow us to display 3 static blocks in a row. You can increase | decrease as your desire. That is up to you. The only thing that need to mention here is `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block1')->toHtml(); ?>` will allow us to show a static block content in a phtml file. You need to specify your static block id instead of this

The only remaining part is, we need to define a css file for holding our css definition

File : `skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/css/test/test.css`

```
.container {
    //custom css code
}
.left-section {
    //custom css code
}
.right-section {
    //custom css code
}
.middle-section {
    //custom css code
}
```

This is one way to achieve this. You can try this. Hope it helps

Comment: What if I don't want to show these same static block sets on every page? How would that change the initial code?

Comment: Hi @Mike, please select the answer as "accepted" if it helped you. This marks this question as resolved and helps this platform to grow. This platform is still in beta and we need an answer rate of 80%. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaVolkl this is really appreciated. Thanks :  -)